# @Transactional in service (SpringMVC + Hibernate) - No Session found for current thread error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactional

I have the ApplicationContextConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.appname")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
public class ApplicationContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getClass().getName());

private static String dbPassKey = null, dbPass = null, dbUserKey = null, dbUser = null, dbNameKey = null, dbName = null, 
        dbServer = null, printHql = null;
static {
    logger.debug("First Step : Loading properties files : start");
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        if(Utils.getEnvironment().equals(Constants.DEVELOPMENT_ENV)) {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(Constants.DEV_DATABASE_CONSTANTS_FILE);
            prop.load(input);
        } else if (Utils.getEnvironment().equals(Constants.TEST_ENV)) {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(Constants.TEST_DATABASE_CONSTANTS_FILE);
            prop.load(input);
        } else {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(Constants.PROD_DATABASE_CONSTANTS_FILE);
            prop.load(input);
        }
        dbPassKey = prop.getProperty("PROPERTY1");
        dbPass = prop.getProperty("PROPERTY2");
        dbUserKey = prop.getProperty("PROPERTY3");
        dbUser = prop.getProperty("PROPERTY4");
        dbNameKey = prop.getProperty("PROPERTY5");
        dbName = prop.getProperty("PROPERTY6");
        dbServer = prop.getProperty("PROPERTY7");
        printHql = prop.getProperty("PROPERTY8");
        logger.debug("First Step : Loading properties files : end");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets").setCachePeriod(31556926);
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
public MultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver mpResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    return mpResolver;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String dbUrl = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(getDbNameKey() + " -----------;;---------- " + getDbName()); 
        dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://"+getDbServer()+":3306/"+GeneratePlainPassword.decrypt(getDbNameKey(), getDbName());
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);

        dataSource.setUsername(GeneratePlainPassword.decrypt(getDbUserKey(), getDbUser()));
        dataSource.setPassword(GeneratePlainPassword.decrypt(getDbPassKey(), getDbPass()));
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    logger.debug("Settings2 : " + dbUrl);
    return dataSource;
}


private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", getPrintHql());
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    return properties;
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.appname.model");
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}



@Autowired
@Bean(name = "processSpectrumService")
public ProcessSpectrumService getProcessSpectrumService() {
    return new ProcessSpectrumServiceImpl();
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "analyserDao")
public AnalyserDAO getAnalyserDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    return new AnalyserDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
}


public static String getDbPassKey() {
    return dbPassKey;
}

public static String getDbPass() {
    return dbPass;
}

public static String getDbUserKey() {
    return dbUserKey;
}

public static String getDbUser() {
    return dbUser;
}

public static String getDbNameKey() {
    return dbNameKey;
}

public static String getDbName() {
    return dbName;
}

public static String getDbServer() {
    return dbServer;
}

public static String getPrintHql() {
    return printHql;
}


}
```

This is my service class:

```
@Service("processSpectrumService")
public class ProcessSpectrumServiceImpl implements 
ProcessSpectrumService {

@Autowired
private AnalyserDAO analyserDao;

@Override
public String processSpectrumDataFile(List<Date> dates, List<DataFile> dataFiles, BatchCompound batchCompound) {
    String status = null;
     try {
          logger.debug("Call Matlab code1");

          List<BatchCompoundCoanalyte> batchCompoundCoanalytes = analyserDao.getCoanalytesForBatchCompound(batchCompound.getBatchCompoundId());
          HashMap<Integer, Code3Output> output = octaveCode2(dataFiles, batchCompound, batchCompoundCoanalytes);

         if(output != null && !output.isEmpty()) {
              status = saveResultsToDB(batchCompound, output);
         }

     }catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         batchCompound.setError(e.getMessage());
         batchCompound = analyserDao.saveBatchCompoundToDatabase(batchCompound);
         status = Constants.PROCESS_STATUS.PROCESS_FAILED;
    }

    return status;
}

@Transactional("transactionManager")
public String saveResultsToDB( BatchCompound batchCompound, HashMap<Integer, Code3Output> outputs) {
String status = null;
try{
  for(int loopCount = 0; loopCount < outputs.size(); loopCount++) {
     Result result = new Result();  //
     //process the datas and get result

     result = analyserDao.saveResultToDatabase(result);
     status = Constants.PROCESS_STATUS.PROCESS_SUCCESS;
  }
}catch(Exception ex){
 batchCompound.setError(Constants.FILE_STATUS.ERROR_IN_PROCESSING);
            batchCompound.setError(ex.getMessage());
            batchCompound = analyserDao.saveBatchCompoundToDatabase(batchCompound);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            status = Constants.PROCESS_STATUS.PROCESS_FAILED;
}
return status;
}
```

And in AnalyserDAOImpl, i have the method:

```
public class AnalyserDAOImpl implements AnalyserDAO {


@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public AnalyserDAOImpl() {
}

public AnalyserDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public BatchCompound saveBatchCompoundToDatabase(BatchCompound batchCompound) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(batchCompound);
    return batchCompound;
}

@Override
public Result saveResultToDatabase(Result result) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(result);
    return result;

}



}
```

The code returns the error at AnalyserDAOImpl:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at 


  org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.appname.dao.AnalyserDAOImpl.saveResultToDatabase(AnalyserDAOImpl.java:309)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.saveResultToDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at com.appname.service.ProcessSpectrumServiceImpl.saveResultsToDB(ProcessSpectrumServiceImpl.java:119)
    at com.appname.service.ProcessSpectrumServiceImpl.processSpectrumDataFile(ProcessSpectrumServiceImpl.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.processSpectrumDataFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.appname.service.AnalyserServiceImpl.processDataFiles(AnalyserServiceImpl.java:413)
    at com.appname.service.AnalyserServiceImpl.automateProcess(AnalyserServiceImpl.java:352)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It works fine when the @Transactional is moved to the method in AnalyserDAOImpl, but then the results will be saved one by one until an error occurs. I want all the results to be saved only if there is no error in the entire result.

Comment: Can you post all of your `AnalyserDAOImpl` code? You might lack some annotation on it

Comment: @DamCx I have updated the question.

Comment: How about ProcessSpectrumService (the interface), does it have any annotations?

Comment: @NajeebaSaidalavi What about the `AnalyserDAO`? No annotation either there? Because from what I see, if you don't have at least a `@Component` annotation somewhere around, it might be a start of answer

Comment: You have @EnableTransactionManagement in the web context level.
Try to move this annotation to Main class (if it is spring boot) or to AOP configuration, because you need transactions in the application context level. Also is clearer to use @ Service for ProcessSpectrucService without bean instantiation.

Comment: @user2612030- there are no annotations in the interfaces. Thank you.

Comment: @DamCx - there are no annotations in the interfaces. Thank you.

Comment: You have @Autowired on your beans, there is no need to do that. Remove them and try again